# Automatically locked on Community Wiki

Tags: support, community-wiki

Can someone take a look at this and tell me what happened?  I edited by original post once after about 30 seconds, and all of a sudden the post got locked in community wiki mode.  I guess the poster could have made it a wiki while I was updating it and changed it back maybe?

[How can you secure/encrypt your querystring in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989703/how-can-you-secure-encrypt-your-querystring-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you accidentally hit the 'community wiki' checkbox below the answer? Maybe hitting `tab` and then `space`?

The original poster could not change his question to CW and then change it back. Changing a question to CW is a one-way process.